# Do I need transit visa in London with an EEA residence permit?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, egyptian-citizens

Do I need a transit visa in London if I am an Egyptian citizen living in Greece with a residence permit? I am travelling from Greece to Italy and I'll do transit landside less than 24 hours.

I read on the [official UK Home Office website that I don't need a visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/egypt/transit/yes) but does it make a difference that I am travelling inside Europe and not outside Europe?

Comment: I think you figured it out. We can repeat the information you found on this page but I am not sure what the question is.

Comment: the question is i know that i have the right to land 
but am anxious that they said why you make transit while ur going to italy not like am going to us or canda

Comment: You need to fulfill at least *one* of the conditions so either going to the US, etc. *or* having a “valid uniform format residence permit issued by an EEA state” (Greece is in the EEA). Going to Italy (which you also have the right to enter by virtue of having a Greek residence permit) should not be an issue.

Comment: I hope it will be like that without any problems .thanks

Comment: @ahmed it will be nice if you add an answer once you are done with the transit, to let us know the real answer. safe flt.

Comment: sure i'll leave answer when i done i believe i'll go to embassy to ask

Comment: that link says you **do** need a visa to transit through the UK

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 Not quite, read the full page.

Comment: ah, the last two points - residence permit issued by an EEA state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [webpage you found](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/egypt/transit/yes), Egyptian citizens generally do need a visa to transit either landside or [airside](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/egypt/transit/no) in London but can be exempted in some cases. Travelling to the US is one of those cases, having an EEA residence permit is another one.

> You might be eligible for the ‘transit without visa concession’ if:
>
> - you arrive and depart by air
> - have a confirmed onward flight which leaves within 24 hours
> - have the right documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country)
>
> **One of the following** must also apply:
>
> […]
>
> - you have a valid uniform format residence permit issued by an EEA state

The first three conditions must be fulfilled to qualify, which seems to be the case for you. Your Greek residence permit gives you the right to enter Italy as both countries are part of the Schengen area (I am assuming you have a [regular Greek residence permit](http://prado.consilium.europa.eu/en/1742/docHome.html), if not then this answer might not apply).

But you only need to fulfill one of the other conditions in the list (in fact, it seems impossible to fulfill them all) and you told us that you do fulfill one of them (namely having a residence permit by an EEA state, as Greece is indeed a member of the EEA). So flying to Italy instead of the US should not be a problem if you fulfill the other relevant conditions.

That said, asking the embassy or even applying for a visa cannot hurt if you want to be absolutely sure (the visa does cost something). You can also ask your airline, as they will want to check your visa status before carrying you to the UK.