# Transit visa for UK if on Dutch residency permit

Tags: uk, transit, lhr, south-african-citizens, dutch-residents

I am a South African living in the Netherlands on a residence permit.

My husband is Dutch, and we are going on holiday to South Africa. I have a flight booked back from South Africa to Amsterdam, via Heathrow.

Do I need a transit visa for the UK? The [gov.uk site](http://www.gov.uk) is not clear about how my Dutch residence permit would apply - and it's very expensive if I do need a visa!

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27006/do-i-need-transit-visa-in-london-with-a-greek-residence-permit?rq=1.  You do not need a transit visa because of your residence permit.  The information is hard to find, but I don't find it unclear.  If you can point out something that you find particularly unclear, please edit your question to explain.

Comment: On the [visa checker](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/south-africa/transit/no) it says you need one unless exempt; one exemption is "a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland"

Comment: I don't think you need a visa but if you would, I see no reason you could not apply for an EEA family permit. Still a hassle and potentially long delays but it should at least be free of charge.

Comment: @Relaxed you are absolutely correct, an EEA family permit would be an option and is free.  Of course, the main issue here is boarding the plane.  Once they're in the UK, since they're traveling together, they will *both* be covered by freedom of movement, no EEA FP needed.