# Transiting the UK with a residence document issued by an European Economic Area country

Tags: uk, transit, transit-visas, egyptian-citizens, italian-residents

I am an Egyptian citizen residing in Italy. I have had family residency for five years. I am traveling from Rome to Iceland with a transit in London. I will pass through the border area to change airports. Will I be allowed to do so?

This is the residence card that I own:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need transit visa in London with an EEA residence permit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27006/do-i-need-transit-visa-in-london-with-an-eea-residence-permit)

Comment: @AndrewLeach the rules have changed because of Brexit.

Comment: Importantly, the document pictured is *not* a common-format residence permit.

Comment: Traveldoc says **NO** with EGY passport and ITA family residence permit

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer.  It is clearly incorrect.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Accourding to [Visa to pass through the UK in transit - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa), persons with a **EEA family permit** (which is what you have) do **not** require a *Visitor in Transit visa* (that allows passing through UK border control and a transit within 48 hours).

The [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/egypt/transit/somewhere_else/yes) (found from inside the above link) also list other exceptions:

- you have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland
- you have a uniform format category D visa for entry to a country in the EEA or Switzerland

**Note**:
The *Transit caseworker guidance* quotes only Article 1 of **(EC) No 1030/2002**.

---

> [2020-12-01 V5: Transit caseworker guidance - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/transit-guidance)
> **DATV: transiting without a DATV** (Page 35 PDF)
> ...
>
> - valid common format Category D visa for entry to an EEA state or Switzerland
> - valid common format residence permit issued by an EEA State pursuant to Council Regulation **(EC) No 1030/2002(1)** or Switzerland
>
> ...

> [The Immigration (Passenger Transit Visa) Order 2014](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2014/2702#reference-c22227531)
> **Exemption from the requirement for a transit passenger to hold a transit visa**
> **Artical 4 (1)**
> ...
> (i) a valid common format Category D visa for entry to an EEA state or Switzerland;
> (j) a valid common format residence permit issued by an EEA State pursuant to Council Regulation (EC) No 1030/2002 <sup>**F14**</sup> or Switzerland;
> ...
>
> > **Changes to legislation**:There are outstanding changes not yet made by the legislation.gov.uk editorial team to The Immigration (Passenger Transit Visa) Order 2014. Any changes that have already been made by the team appear in the content and are referenced with annotations.
> >
> > - <sub>**F14**: OJ L157, 15.6.02, **p. 1**.</sub>

> **Council Regulation [(EC) No 1030/2002](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32002R1030) of 13 June 2002 laying down a uniform format for residence permits for third-country nationals**
>
> *Official Journal L 157 , 15/06/2002 P. 0001 - 0007*
>
> **Article 1**
>
> 1. Residence permits issued by Member States to third-country nationals shall be drawn up in a uniform format and provide sufficient space for the information set out in the Annex hereto. The uniform format may be used as a sticker or a stand-alone document. Each Member State may add in the relevant space of the uniform format information of importance regarding the nature of the permit and the legal status of the person concerned, in particular information as to whether or not the person is permitted to work.
>
> 2. For the purpose of this Regulation,
>
> (a) "residence permit" shall mean **any authorisation issued by the authorities of a Member State allowing a third-country national to stay legally on its territory**, with the exception of:
>
> > (i) visas;
> >
> > (ii) permits issued pending examination of an application for a residence permit or for asylum;
> >
> > (iii) authorisations issued for a stay of a duration not exceeding six months by Member States not applying the provisions of Article 21 of the Convention implementing the Schengen Agreement of 14 June 1985 between the Governments of the States of the Benelux Economic Union, the Federal Republic of Germany and the French Republic on the gradual abolition of checks at their common borders(9);
>
> (b) "third-country national" shall mean any person who is not a citizen of the Union within the meaning of Article 17(1) of the Treaty.

---

**Sources**:

- [2020-12-01 V5: Transit caseworker guidance - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/transit-guidance)

  - [2020-12-30: Travel Eligibility to the UK for EU/EEA and Swiss Nationals and their Families from 23:00hrs on 31 December 2020 - Ethiopian Airlines](https://www.ethiopianairlines.com/docs/default-source/default-document-library/ca-36-20---revised-version---travel-eligibility-for-eu-eea-and-swiss-nationals-from-01-january-2021.pdf) (PDF)
- [The Immigration (Passenger Transit Visa) Order 2014](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2014/2702#reference-c22227531)

  - [(EC) No 1030/2002](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32002R1030)

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  An EEA family permit is a document that was formerly issued by the UK, but is no longer issued because the UK has withdrawn from the European Union.  The document shown above is an article 10 card issued by Italy, and the EEA FP was an article 10 card issued by the UK, but the UK _never_ used the phrase "EEA family permit" to refer to article 10 cards issued by other countries.

Comment: @phoog If you make the effort to look at the UK site, you will see that that is the term they used there. The second link shows a more comprehensive list of visas and residence permit types from many different countries that also qualify (but are not shown on the main page). The relevant portion that covers the OP was included in the answer. The answer is correct. The OP **does not** require a transit visa.

Comment: @MarkJohnson And that list does *not* include the document shown by the OP (it's not in the “common format”). Even it did, it still remains that it is not an EEA family permit. After your edits, your answer confuses several things, quotes outdated documents and ist still plain wrong. Your habit of never ever editing anything out nor correcting mistakes while dumping irrelevant extensive quotes and oddly formatted links to try to hide them is becoming very dangerous here.

Comment: Also: "relevant” is spelled "relevant”, not "relavent". Curious to see if you find a website to pretend that's not the case.

Comment: @Relaxed Both the *Transit guidance for entry clearance and Border Force staff* and *The Immigration (Passenger Transit Visa) Order 2014* are the lastest available versions. Feel free to supply your own answer that Article 10 residence card holders are required to apply for a *Visitor in Transit visa*.

Comment: "p. 1" means page 1, not article 1. In any case, OP's document is not in the common format. You quoted the definition of a residence permit, not the definition of a "common format residence permit", which can be only interpreted as a residence permit issued in the uniform format laid down by EC 1030/2002. EC 1030/2002 only concerns the format, not motives. OP's document is not in the uniform format.

Comment: @MarkJohnson You're the one answering here, I made absolutely no claim regarding that and it's on you to provide evidence for your claims (and clear up all the mistakes, even if the conclusion would happen to be correct by chance). Also, it's “relevant”, not “relavant” either (but kudos for using the edit function, we are slowing getting somewhere).

Comment: Importantly, none of the sources you quoted say anything about “article 10” residence cards (for the most part, that stopped being relevant with Brexit). They are about “common format residence permit”. In fact, the document you found on Ethiopian Airlines explicitely states that “From 23:00  (UK  Time)  31  December  2020, EU  and  Irish-issued Article 10/20 cards will no longer be acceptable as a visa exemption document.”

Comment: So what are you relying on to reach your conclusion? The common format or the basis for the residence card? And why are you asking me about article 10 residence cards? It's this kind of confusion, loosely jumping from one norm to the other, that makes it difficult for you to understand anything about immigration rules and leads to dangerously bad advice.

Comment: @Relaxed For Visitors: yes, but: **Transit Exemption Documents** *The UK **will continue to accept** the same EU/EEA and Swiss common format Category D visas and **residence permits** as exemption documents for the purpose of transiting the UK without a visa.* The *Transit guidance for entry clearance and Border Force staff* states *(EC) No 1030/2002(1)* where **residence permit** is defined as *shall mean any authorisation issued by the authorities of a Member State allowing a third-country national to stay legally on its territory*. The residence card fullfills this condition.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's exactly what I was referring to: This is about residence permits *qua* residence permits. Why do you ask me about residence 10 residence cards then? Once we have clarified the legal basis, we can move on to examine whether the document pictured fulfills the requirements (it does not). Do you accept that article 10 residence cards from other countries do not open any specific exemption as such?

Comment: @Relaxed The intension of *The Immigration (Passenger Transit Visa) Order 2014 (4)(1)* is a list of documents that garanties that the transit travellers can enter or return to their point of destination/departure. The suttelties of the different types is not their concern.

Comment: @zhantongz That may, indeed, be the case. The *Transit guidance for entry clearance and Border Force staff* does quote *(EC) No 1030/2002(1)* directly.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That also doesn't mean Article 1. No one, at least in any UK (or any English EU) legal publication, refers to articles in that way. It is almost certainly a result of careless copying by the editing staff from https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2014/2702/article/4/made.

Comment: And I'm not sure why you keep ignoring "common format". They are not just adding the words for fun. Many people on Spanish student residence permit (NIE) got denied boarding or got stuck at immigration because it was not in the common format.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Indeed, which, again, is precisely why you introduce confusion by referring to article 10 specifically. I see you're still dodging the question. Now, let's examine what residence permits create an exemption for transit. You seem to be implying that it's the case for “*any authorisation issued by the authorities of a Member State allowing a third-country national to stay legally on its territory*”, correct?

Comment: @zhantongz It's because Mark never ever recognises any mistakes or edit his answers. Without this sleight of hand and the confusion between article 10 residence cards, residence permits in general and common-format residence permits, the plain meaning of the sources he quotes would become inescapable.

Comment: @Relaxed Yes, just as all of the 22 exceptions in Article 4(1) that mainly deal with Australia, Canada, New Zealand and the US (including long term visas).

Comment: @MarkJohnson Good so we don't have to get into the niceties of regulation 1030/2002 because this conclusion is absurd on its face. It wasn't the case before Brexit and it isn't the case now. The “check if you need a UK visa” website and the caseworker guidance are crystal clear, the exemption covers “common format residence permit” (i.e. not all of them, just those in the common format). How is there any doubt in your mind about that?

Comment: "If you make the effort to look at the UK site, you will see that that is the term they used there": I have looked at that site probably more than 100 times.  I know they use the term "EEA family permit."  I also know that when they use that term they are referring to the document formerly issued by the United Kingdom.  The term does not include article 10 cards (nor any other document) issued by any other country.

Answer (score 4):

Your residence card **does not** suffice for visa-free transit in the UK.

[The Guide from the UK government to airlines](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/947061/Charging_Procedures_-_A_Guide_for_Carriers.pdf) mentions explicitly the need for a common format residence permit, that is, a credit card-sized plastic card or sticker in passport with either a bull (old format) or an European map (new format) on it.

The only residence permit issued *pursuant to* EC 1030/2002 is one in the specified format. Other permits not subject to EC 1030/2002 are of course not issued based on EC 1030/2002.

> Passengers having a valid common format residence permit issued by an EEA
> state or Switzerland.
> Passengers who have a valid common format residence permit issued by an EEA
> state or Switzerland do not have to be travelling to or from the country which issued
> the permit. Please note that there are several forms of residence permits issued by
> EEA states but **the only acceptable permits are those which are issued following the
> directions given in the Council Regulation (EC) No. 1030/2002.**
>
> These permits may take the form of a vignette (sticker) in a passport or a plastic card.
> There are several common features of these cards all set out in the directive – the
> permits are coloured mainly pink and blue, each has an EU Kinegram, also printed on
> the permits is the image of a bull and five stars. **All other permits such as the large A4-sized Italian Permesso di Soggiorno, or an Irish Work Permit sticker are not common
> format residence permits and are not acceptable as an exemption document for DATV
> nationals seeking to TWOV.**

Answer (score 3):

If I were you I would get a visa.

The document you have is not an EEA family permit, which was the name the UK gave to the documents that *it* issued like the document you have, but the UK never used that name to denote such documents issued by other countries.

The document you have is not a common-format residence permit.  It is certainly a residence permit, but it is not in the common format specified by European Union law.

The document is not a visa of any sort, and it is certainly not a uniform format visa.

Now obviously in the *spirit* of the transit visa exemptions you ought to be able to transit without a visa.  But the document you have does not comply with the *letter* of these restrictions.  It is better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Note: making such an application costs £64, so this is very bad advice.

Comment: If my family residence is not what is intended, then is the residence of a worker, for example, or a refugee, which is issued in the form of a plastic card is the intended purpose?

Comment: The *The Immigration (Passenger Transit Visa) Order 2014 (4)(j)* refers **only** to Article 1 of *(EC) No 1030/2002* (thus ignores Article 5 which exclude family members).

Comment: @MarkJohnson What's the bigger risk? GBP 64 per person for an application or being denied boarding, losing all the money in the tickets or worse getting in trouble with British authorities?

Comment: @BLALALI The intention of the regulation is that all countries eventually move to the plastic cards, many other EU countries have already done it and do issue plastic cards to people in your situation. Most regular residence permits (workers, students) are certainly covered as well. Documents issued to refugees vary (and they also need a passport/travel document, which might trigger other rules for transit).

Comment: I am now confused and do not understand something. I want, please, a direct answer. Is the residency that I possess and that Italy does not issue other than residency for family members of European Union citizens is the intended stay, or no, I do not want a simple and direct answer without going into complicated details that I do not understand. Thank you in any case.

Comment: @BLALALI You will need a visa if all you have is your passport and the Italian paper-format residence permit.

Comment: @BLALALI the direct answer is that this document is not sufficient, because it is not a "common format" document.  See zhantongz's [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163198/transiting-the-uk-with-a-residence-document-issued-by-an-european-economic-area#comment410401_163199): "Many people on Spanish student residence permit (NIE) got denied boarding or got stuck at immigration because it was not in the common format."

Comment: @MarkJohnson "The Immigration (Passenger Transit Visa) Order 2014 (4)(j) refers only to Article 1 of (EC) No 1030/2002 (thus ignores Article 5 which exclude family members)": that is correct. The effect of the exclusion in 1030/2002 Art. 5 is that EU countries are not required to use the common format for the residence cards they issue to these family members under 2004/38/EC Art. 10 or 20, and Italy has chosen to use a different format.  That is why the document in the question is not a common format document.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the UK has at times expressed concern about the ease of forging some EU documents, and about how the multiplicity of document formats makes it even more difficult to detect forgeries.  In that light, it makes sense for the UK to accept only common format documents.  It is more difficult to establish that other documents are genuine.

Comment: @phoog There is the claim that 'identity cards are some of the least secure documents' ([Government publishes updated GB-EU Border Operating Model - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/government-publishes-updated-gb-eu-border-operating-model)). To my knowledge they use the same technology as passports. For paper documents this claim would be justified, but could be added to [Passenger Transit Visa Order 2014, Artical 4 (3)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2014/2702#reference-key-7b9cbef7a17130d11e02dc5dfa881746), where presently *electronic formats* are excluded from eligibility.

Comment: @phoog The problem seems to me, that in this case 2 Egyptian citizens living in Italy, one a spouse of an EU Citizen (resident card) requires a Transit Visa, while the other that has a residence permit does not need a Transit Visa an unlikely scenario.

Comment: @MarkJohnson if document security is taken into account, it is not surprising that the two would be treated differently, since one has a polycarbonate document full of security features while the other has a paper document with relatively few security features.  "For paper documents this claim would be justified, but could be added...": It doesn't need to be added because it is already present in the phrase "common format residence permit."

Answer (score 0):

> I will pass through the border area to change airports. Will I be allowed to do so?

As a general rule in any country, in order to change airports you need a full permission to enter the transit country (visa or visa-exemption), namely as a tourist.

Your transit circumstance **makes no difference** within the scope of the question, if you must change airport or terminal. Even if you can show air tickets, the general rule is that you must prove that you have right to enter and **stay** in the transit country. This check will be enforced in Rome, where the airline is responsible for boarding.

The explanation is super simple. A person with intent to illegally immigrate into the UK could buy a fake onward ticket and not use it. After clearing immigration, one is free to go anywhere.

Comment: (+1) Excellent point, although the UK does have special rules for just that scenario. You still need a [visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa) but it's a cheaper one with different requirements than a Standard Visitor visa. The Visitor in Transit visa doesn't give you the right to stay for more than 48 hours in the UK.

Comment: Many countries, including the UK, have a transit visa that does allow passing through immigration controls but does not allow staying for tourism, business, or or other purposes normally associated with short-term visits.